# Swift: Adding UILabel to UIScrollView fails to scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I am dynamically creating my UILabels for a tiny calculator. The calculator takes two inputs, number of days and an initial pay, and pumps out the total money made for each day. The calculator takes the initial payment, doubles it, and provides an answer in this form:

```
On day 1, daily pay earned was $2.00
Total pay earned was $2.00
On day 2, daily pay earned was $4.00
Total pay earned was $6.00
On day 3, daily pay earned was $8.00
Total pay earned was $14.00
```

The following is a screenshot of the interface:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wunbtzyqzenrwru/Screenshot%202015-04-27%2002.40.44.png?dl=0

Along with the StoryBoard: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzuouje60x7v7k0/Screenshot%202015-04-27%2002.41.49.png?dl=0

Where

```
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
```

The following is the operation I coded to generate the labels. The problem comes from the last line most likely.

```
for comments in printArr {
    println(comments)
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 42))
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.988, green: 0.431, blue: 0.318, alpha: 1.0)
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.center = CGPointMake(200, 0 + spacer )
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 12)
    label.text = comments
    spacer = spacer + 50
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(label)
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply adding subview is not enough. You need to set the `contentSize` of scroll view to make it scroll.

```
self.ScrollView.contentSize = TOTAL_SIZE_OF_ALL_YOUR_LABEL
```

Comment: Completely missed that D: Using your suggestion, I solved it doing this:
   var heightScroll = CGFloat(printArr.count * 50);
   ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, heightScroll + CGFloat(30))

Answer (score 3):

You have to set a proper scrollView.contentSize. This is the rectangle, which you can scroll over. For example, this code sets the contentView to 2 times the height of the UIWindow:

```
let fullScreenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: fullScreenRect)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(fullScreenRect.width, fullScreenRect.height*2.0)
```